# elasticsearch field populated with object Object

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

My index defines this column as:

> :service_data => { :type => 'string', :index => 'no' }

and I am populating it with an array of JSONs

In elastic HQ i see the data as:

> [object Object],[object Object]...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: More details required

Comment: I figured it out... all i did is to serialize the data that I was saving there (.to_yaml)